# book return ticket with additional traveller on return ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, india

I want to book a return flight to India but on my return flight, my wife will be accompanying me. How do you do this on air-travel websites? Because return tickets are extremely cheap compared to one way tickets.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Just both passengers on the same flight? Or are you trying to get a cheaper fare for her?  Or something else?

Comment: if roundtrips are still cheaper, you have the option to buy her a ticket India-US-India, and throw away the second half. Note: You can*not* do it the other way around, and throw away the first half - the ticket becomes voided.

Comment: @ Doc: I am trying to achieve both. I want to us to be on the same flight with seating together and a cheaper fare aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have different itineraries you will need two different bookings and there is no easy way to link the two bookings together. Your best bet is to book early with the same airlines and reserve seats together while there are still plenty of open spots.

These days, one way tickets are typically NOT more expensive than round trip tickets. For example FRA-DEL in mid Feb is around $600 for a round trip and around $450 for a one way.